# Unable to access Ubuntu in a dual boot system. “Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word,....”

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I have a Ubuntu and windows dual boot, and it was working well for a year. Today, while using Ubuntu, I kept a live usb drive with windows recovery (I was not aware of this). I couldn’t access the files In pen drive on Ubuntu, So I opened a terminal and decided to switch to windows and used the command (with the usb attached to pc)

`sudo reboot now`

And all of a sudden I am getting this
[image]

I am able to access windows by using the command “exit” and then choosing windows but getting the above screen when I choose Ubuntu
. I want to use Ubuntu now with all files restored.

There were similar questions on this but all of them occurred during the process of dual booting. Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Does this still happen if you remove the USB before rebooting?

Comment: The pic in question is what is appearing when I start my PC with and without the usb.  It never happened before.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the usb was formatted